# How do I substitute within an expression using ggplot2?

Tags: r, expression, ggplot2, evaluation

I would like to get the latex symbol for beta with a subscript of 2.

The following code:

```
idx <- 2;
ylab(eval(expression(paste("beta[",idx,"]",sep=""))))
```

produces the label "beta[2]" instead of "\beta_{2}".  What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** to see what I want, just use `ylab(expression(beta[2]))`, but I want to pull the value out of the variable `idx` instead of using a hard-coded value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use bquote. Here is a sample code snippet

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 = qplot(tip, data = tips)
idx = 2;
my.ylab = bquote(beta[2] == .(idx))
p1 + ylab(my.ylab)
```

Comment: Wonderful!!  That's exactly what I wanted -- though I ended up using `myLabel = bquote( beta[.(idx2)]);`